# How to implement conditional branching inside Data Flow Task of SSIS package?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, dataflowtask

In package i have one Data Flow task which execute an SQL query and return some columns.

I want to check value of one of the Source column, whether it is 1 or 0.
If the column value is 1, then  insert the record in table Source_Error_tbl (redirect error record)
If the column value is 0, then insert the record in destination table (general flow)

Can anyone help on how can we implement this if-else condition inside data Flow task ??

Precedence constraint i checked, but it cannot be implemented inside data flow task.

Comment: [Conditional Split Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/conditional-split-transformation?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Like @Filburt said, conditional split. You should get used to that object as it is also used after a Lookup to determine if the row is an insert or update.

Comment: @Filburt thank you guys on helping to take initial steps in SSIS.